# Can not send email threw SwiftMailer with Mandrill

Tags: php, swiftmailer, mandrill

Since today, many of my php applications can not send email using SwiftMailer and different Mandrill accounts.

I've got this code, and the send function in the last if stop the script..

```
// Instance message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();

$message->setSubject("subject")
        ->setFrom(array('noreply@email.test' => 'test'))
        ->setTo(array('a_valid_email' => 'name'))
        ->setBody("test", 'text/html')
        ->setPriority(2);

$smtp_host     = 'smtp.mandrillapp.com';
$smtp_port     = 587;
$smtp_username = 'valid_username';
$smtp_password = 'valid_password';

// SMTP
$smtp_param = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance($smtp_host , $smtp_port)
        ->setUsername($smtp_username)
        ->setPassword($smtp_password);

// Instance Swiftmailer
$instance_swiftmailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($smtp_param);

$type = $message->getHeaders()->get('Content-Type');
$type->setValue('text/html');
$type->setParameter('charset', 'iso-8859-1');

//Here the send function stop event and I did not go inside the if      
    if ($instance_swiftmailer->send($message, $fail)) {
        echo 'OK ';
    }else{
        echo 'NOT OK : ';
        print_r($fail);
    }
```

Thank you in advance to help me to solve this problem..

Comment: What's the actual error you're getting when you run the code? What is the failure message?

Answer (score -1):

If your code used to work, and now doesn't work, and you didn't change your code, then it's probably not a problem with your code. Check your Mandrill account validity - sometimes they suspend accounts for suspicious-appearing usage.